# aurel32 qemu images arm vs mips

Tags: arm, mips, qemu, initrd

I am currently learning how to emulate both mips(el) and arm architecture using Qemu. The images which I used for both architecture is by aurel32 from this website, https://people.debian.org/%7Eaurel32/qemu/

I noticed that the mips images does not have initrd while the arm images have initrd. I am unsure why arm requires initrd when running Qemu but mips does not.

Anyone know why this is the case?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no inherent reason -- you can build an Arm kernel with enough devices built-in to not need an initrd, and you can build a MIPS kernel that does require an initrd. You'd have to ask Aurelien why the two sets of images he built had different configs (assuming he even remembers 6 years later!), but I suspect it's just that [for MIPS he was able to use the stock Debian kernel](https://www.aurel32.net/info/debian_mips_qemu.php) whereas [for Arm he had to compile his own kernel](https://www.aurel32.net/info/debian_arm_qemu.php), and so the configuration choices for the two weren't identical.